# returning an array of bool in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm generating a 56bits string of 0 and 1.

so this is my code :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "genkey.h"

static char * genkey()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rr;
    char key[7];

    for(int ii = 0; ii < 7; ii++)
    {
    key[ii] = rand() % 255;
    }

    return *key;
}

int main()
{
    char truc[64] = genkey();
    printf("%s", truc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I can't compile it. And I don't understand why.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: no a bool is not 1 bit! it's one **byte**. The most memory efficient way to store bits, is to use bitmasks over bytes.

Comment: oh right. C doesn't seem to be able to handle bit in its typedef. So char it is. I edited my code.

Comment: ***Why can't you compile it?***

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. That variable goes out of scope once the function returns. This leads to *undefined behavior* when you try to dereference this pointer.

Not to mention that you will get compilation errors first because you don't actually returns a pointer (`return *key` returns the value that `key` is pointing to) and that you can't initialize an array in that way in the `main` function.

I would recommend that you instead of returning a pointer, you pass the array as an argument to the function for initialization. So e.g.

```
void genkey(bool *key)
{
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    bool truc[64];
    genkey(truc);

    ...
}
```

Comment: The code is not dealing with bits as well.  Look into bitwise operations

Answer (score 1):

This is very wrong. You are returning pointer to a local no longer existing array. Use

```
void genkey(bool* key, unsigned size)
... (of course without declaring key in the function)

bool key[64];
genkey(key, 64); // better to use #define instead
```

BTW bool is NOT one bit, but one byte.

Comment: do we have bool in C?

Comment: Yes, it was introduced in C99.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're declaring an array of 64 **bytes** each of them containing only one boolean information, 1 or 0. If you want to be memory efficient, use a bitmask on one or several bytes.

Then here's how to solve your problem:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "genkey.h"

bool* genkey(bool* key)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int rr;

    for(int ii = 0; ii < 64; ii++)
    {
    rr = rand();
    key[ii] = rr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool key[64];
    genkey(key);
    printf("%s", truc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

please go read the [K&R](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf) or even better that documentation http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/cdescent/ that is aimed at people coming from higher abstraction languages. You need to learn about memory management and scope of variables!

Answer (score 0):

In C, functions can only return simple types, not arrays.

```
static bool* genkey()
{
    bool key[64];
    ...
    return *key;
}
```

Here `key` is a `bool*`, yet you are trying to return `*key`, which dereferences `key` and therefore returns its first element. This is obviously not a pointer to a `bool` (i.e. a `bool*`) as the function declaration says.

Let's say you change it to what I think you meant:

```
static bool* genkey()
{
    bool key[64];
    ...
    return key;
}
```

This is still wrong, because `key` is a pointer to an array that was allocated on the stack. When the function exits, the contents of `key[]` will be lost. Returning a pointer to that `key` array is therefore always the wrong thing to do, because it may be undefined.

What you need to do is allocate the array on the heap, and free it in the caller after it has been used. Something like:

```
static bool* genkey()
{
    bool *key = malloc(64 * sizeof bool);
    ...
    return key;
}

int main()
{
    bool *truc = genkey();
    ...
    free (truc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As an alternative, allocate the array in `main()` (on the heap or the stack) and pass a pointer to `genkey`.

Remaining problems left for an exercise for the reader:

1. Error handling.
2. You cannot `printf` a pointer to an array of booleans and expect a sensible result.
3. Using an array of `bool` is not an efficient way to store a bitfield; admittedly it is readable, and for 64 bytes, one might say 'who cares?'

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems in your code. Besides what others have said, you're assigning a value to an array

```
char truc[64] = genkey();
```

which is forbidden in C. An array can only be initialized by values in `{ }` pair. That's why the program didn't compile

Worse, the return value of the function is a byte in the array, not the address. Even if it's the address, you will face undefine behavior since it's a local array which ends its life after exitting the scope. Also, you generate 8 bytes in the program and then expect it to assign into 64 bytes in `main`

And the error list still isn't end. You call printf without including "stdio.h". Enable the warnings, you'll see a implicit declaration of function message.

One more thing, main in C is `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example.

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* allocates an array of random bits
 * char [0]{bit0, bit1, bit2, ... bit7}, char[1]{bit8, bit9 ... }
 */
unsigned char * genKey(int numberOfBits) {

    unsigned char *key = malloc((numberOfBits + 7) / 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBits; i++) {

        int idx = i / 8;
        int mod = i % 8;
        unsigned char bit = (rand() & 1) << (7 - mod);

        key[idx] |= bit;
    }
    return key;
}

/* prints an array of bits.
 * Order: bitN, bitN-1, bitN-2, ...
 */
void printKey(unsigned char *key, int numberOfBits) {

    for (int i = numberOfBits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        int idx = i / 8;
        int mod = i % 8;
        unsigned char bit = 1 << (7 - mod);

        printf("%c", (key[idx] & bit) ? '1' : '0');
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    int bits = 56;
    unsigned char *key = genKey(bits);

    printKey(key, bits);
    free(key);

    return 0;
}
```